# NSPredicate for matching property

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

What in the world am I doing wrong here? Frustrated beyond belief.

I have an array that contains a certain type of object with a property. We'll just call that property "number". It is of type `NSUInteger`.

I also have an entity that has an attribute of "number", with a type of `Integer 64`.

I'm trying to create a fetch request that finds me all the objects in my Core Data store that *do not* exist in the other array with objects.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (%@.number IN number)",someArrayWithObjects];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *notMatchingObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

This returns a nil array. I know that I have objects with numbers in my local store that do not exist in my other array. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that NSArrays are key-value coding compliant and will give you an array of property values with `valueForKey:` (For NSUInteger it will wrap them in NSNumbers)

```
NSArray *predicateInts = [someArrayWithObjects valueForKey:@"number"];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (number IN %@)",predicateInts];
```

Comment: Why can you not do `@"number NOT IN %@.number"`?

Comment: I think it's because the NSPredicate parser is not key-value coding compliant with sets like that, but NSArray *is*.

Comment: Even so, this still doesn't work as expected. I have numbers on my local machine that are not in the other array, and the return of this is still nil.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create an array of `NSNumber` objects that contains just the numbers that you want to exclude.

Then you can use the following fetch request:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (number IN %@)", arrayWithNumbers];
```